# Use of Airbus WorldDem altimetric values (EGM2008)

Tags: dem, altitude

In France, the altimetric values are issued from a mesure of heights above the sea level based on the Marseille's tide gauge. If i didn't mess it up, the system is named NGF - IGN69 for mainland (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_levelling_of_France).

In the dataset named WorldDEM from Airbus, I see the vertical reference is EGM2008 (Ref : http://www.engesat.com.br/wp-content/uploads/663-2015_04_worlddem_technicalspecs_version2.pdf)

Are those two compatible ? Can I compare/mix both and/or does one needs to do a transformation to be in the same altimetric system ? Said differently : can I use WorldDem in France without doing any transformation/shift ?